# Trying to install this git+https://github.com/mmabrouk/chatgpt-wrapper on my windows terminal

Tags: python, linux, windows, git

```
Resolved https://github.com/mmabrouk/chatgpt-wrapper to commit f2d1101cb2f0e1b57fa9fef647a0eef04fea7e5c
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Cesmz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jgb3slo2\setup.py", line 2, in <module>
          from chatgpt_wrapper.chatgpt import VERSION
        File "C:\Users\Cesmz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jgb3slo2\chatgpt_wrapper\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
          from .chatgpt import ChatGPT
        File "C:\Users\Cesmz\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-jgb3slo2\chatgpt_wrapper\chatgpt.py", line 16, in <module>
          from rich.console import Console
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rich'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried it on Kali and it worked fine, but kali is not supported by playwright. I need playwright to run the chatgpt command...
Anyone know what OS can run these commands in https://github.com/mmabrouk/chatgpt-wrapper ?

Comment: looks like playwright doesnt work on windows as well...
Anyone know what can install the above mentioned wrapper and also supported by playwright. "playwright install"

Comment: What python version is used? Did you try to install `rich` before that?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Have followed the installation instructions from https://github.com/mmabrouk/chatgpt-wrapper/blob/main/README.md? Have you reviewed the issues on the respective repository?